# Add command icon to Debug window

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse Helios, I'd like to add the icon for "Run to Line" to the other step-related icons at the top of the Debug window. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the work right now, through [bug 258767](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=258767):

> In debug view, there are only few icons, e.g. "step into", "step over".
>   But there is no "Run to line" icon.

You can see the [patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=185360) [in progress](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=203431) to see how it would be done.